# SvelteKit - get protocol

Tags: sveltekit

Is it possible in SvelteKit to get protocol of current page (HTTP or HTTPS)?

Something like:

```
import {page} from '$app/stores';

console.log($page.protocol);
```

So far, I only see:

```
{
  host: 'localhost:3000',
  path: '/projektDetalji',
  query: URLSearchParams { 'id' => '1' },
  params: {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `browser` to make sure you are running in browser, then grab protocol from `window.location.protocol`.

```
<script context="module">
  import { browser } from "$app/env"
  if (browser) {
    console.log(window.location.protocol);
  }
</script>
```

From `$app/env` module section of [sveltekit docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-env)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way...

Within the `handle()` function of your `hooks.server.js,` the protocol can be gleaned using  `event.url?.protocol` and then passed into the rest of your application via the `locals` object. For example...

```
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Handle} */
export async function handle({ event, resolve }) {
     
     // Store the protocol in the locals object, which is passed 
     // in to handlers in +server.js and server load() functions
     
     event.locals.protocol = event.url?.protocol;
     return await resolve(event);
}
```

Later, retrieve it from the locals object in your `+page.server.js` files...

```
export async function load({params, locals}) {
    if (locals.protocol) {
        console.log ('Protocol is ' + locals.protocol);
    }
}
```